# Callbacks aren't working in model decorator Rails 5 Spree 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm new to Rails 5/Spree 4, but I can't get callbacks to work in my model.  I'm wanting to run some methods after a product is created in Spree, but I don't understand this `included do` stuff that is totally new to me.

Model: `app/models/spree/product_decorator.rb`

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module Spree
  module ProductDecorator
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        after_create :assign_prototype
    end

    def assign_prototype
        binding.pry
    end

  end
end
```

I assume I'm overlooking something stupid, but I've been messing with this for an hour now.  Why isn't the `after_create` method being recognized here?

Comment: did you include this module to the model like `include Spree::ProductDecorator `

Answer (score 4):

This is the actual example given [in the docs](https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/customization/logic.html):

```
module MyStore
  module Spree
    module ProductDecorator
      def some_method
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end

::Spree::Product.prepend MyStore::Spree::ProductDecorator
```

As you can see nothing actually happens if you don't include/prepend `::Spree::Product` with your module. And you also should place your code in your own module so that you don't clobber an existing `Spree::ProductDecorator`.

```
included do
  # ...
end
```

Has nothing to do with Spree. Its all [ActiveSupport::Concern](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) and wraps this common Ruby idiom:

```
module Spree
  module ProductDecorator
    def self.included(base)
      base.class_eval do
        after_create :assign_prototype
      end
    end

    def assign_prototype
      binding.pry
    end
  end
end
```

[`Module#included`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-included) is a hook built into Ruby that lets you execute code in the context of the class when a module is included in a class. Thats how you do accessors, validations, callbacks etc or anything else you would normally do in the body of a model class in a module mixin.